# Android Studio findViewById(R.id.button1) error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Having findViewById(R.id.button1) gives me an error. It was telling me to change the code to findViewById(android.R.id.button1). I do have a button with the id "button1". When I closed the project and restarted it and after I  waited for Gradle to finish loading and the error disappeared. Why does this happen?

Comment: I assume you are using Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Ok. I would see this same kind of thing in Eclipse all the time. I was focusing on the error and missed that detail. The fix was the same in Eclipse: only a restart would correct the problem.

Comment: I don't "know" why it happens. My theory is that the subsystem that is keeping all of the documents, libraries, and references straight loses its way sometimes. If there was a way to cause that system to "refresh" or "reload", then it may be able to straighten the problem out without a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error a few times before. All you need to do is close the project and open it again. Sometimes it's good to just close Eclipse completely. After you open the project again, the error should be gone because the IDE removes it. If you're still getting this error, there might be something wrong in your code. Post a LogCat if the error persists and we can see what is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming it is the same as Eclipse, it happens randomly. Apps I have made will come up with these kind of errors, to simply put it closing the project and opening it again will cause the IDE to remove these errors. If it persists there is an error in your code.